# Filter values that are on a range of rows on google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to filter couple of codes on google sheets but it is a range of values.

On the colum original are all the codes that I've it and I want to create a new column with the codes on the filter column out of it.

I was trying to use the function filter [**filter(A2:A,A2:A<>B2:B)**] but as is a range of values, it only takes the first line. I also tried with query, but I've the same issue.

```
original    filter
Bgk3lUxIRbQ SCjsMoiTv-U
8_yFDcYSbdk RvrH8d-2QC0
video ID L0 vjPEWgAHYn8
TRCAP3URkI0 jWBhOP-hSQo
6iVi8wjA3Ko b2VRWJkNM6g
SBgP0xQCxEM EI7NkW6aF74
qV_i6-NijsE Ls7M5PxM8cc
hQMURWV1EBQ ZY-BR-CZPIs
vrNekZVjQ38 
9pjx7n_sIm4 
owJQQlp8KLA 
Bgk3lUxIRbQ 
8_yFDcYSbdk 
kPpNi6SHYMk 
kqKPXS9wVA4 
QUYx8m8HqJA 
TkqQbtKuinI 
SCjsMoiTv-U 
video ID L0 
video ID L0 
wAsBZ36kDd0 
8NS9d806Q8Q 
RvrH8d-2QC0 
vjPEWgAHYn8 
jWBhOP-hSQo 
video ID L0 
qV_i6-NijsE 
hQMURWV1EBQ 
TkqQbtKuinI 
rhspLssYqug 
vjPEWgAHYn8 
video ID L0 
PHM_q0fqaHo 
kqKPXS9wVA4 
e5DrB2rz170 
b2VRWJkNM6g 
EI7NkW6aF74 
jWBhOP-hSQo 
video ID L0 
9pjx7n_sIm4 
Bgk3lUxIRbQ 
VCfm6jxxfd0 
RTlVXL9iyy4 
3hxupZ96_iM 
Ls7M5PxM8cc 
EI7NkW6aF74 
ZY-BR-CZPIs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Custom Function Solution:

*One way of doing this would be to create a custom function for Google Sheets*.

#### Creating the Formula:

From the Tools > Script editor menu item, you can create a function with the following code:

```js
function LISTFILTER(rangeToFilter, itemsToFilter) {
  rangeToFilter = rangeToFilter.flat();
  itemsToFilter = itemsToFilter.flat();
  var filteredList = [];
  rangeToFilter.forEach(function(item) {
    if (!itemsToFilter.includes(item)) {
      filteredList.push(item);
    }
  });
  return filteredList;
}
```

Save the script with the save icon, and close the script tab.

#### Using the Function:

In a cell, you can call this function as follows:

```
=LISTFILTER(RangeToFilter, ListOfItemsToFilter)
```

For example, if you want to filter all the items in column B out of column A, you could write:

```
=LISTFILTER(A2:A,B2:B)
```

Which, for your example, will yield the following output:

[image]

Here, column C is filled with all the data in column A that is not also in column B.

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets  |  Apps Script  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)